# Rails console issues using JRuby: no prompt character, no tab completion, broken arrow keys, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, rails-console

I'm having various issues with my Rails console under JRuby, including

- No prompt character
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion not working (literal tab gets inserted)
- Up/down arrows not browsing history (`^[[A` or `^[[B` gets inserted, respectively)
- Left/right arrows not moving cursor (`^[[D` or `^[[C` gets inserted, respectively)
- <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> keys not moving cursor to beginning/end of line (instead `1~` or `4~` inserted, respectively); <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> work though
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> killing console instead of killing the line I'm entering
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> not having any effect until I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (which then executes anything I entered between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> in my Unix shell).

I installed my JRuby interpreter from rvm like so:

```
rvm install jruby-1.6.8 --1.9
```

My Rails project is managed using Bundler (not rvm gemsets), so I run my Rails console using `bundle exec rails c`.  Interestingly, raw `irb` as well as `bundle exec irb` don't have most of the above issues, except the <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> keys and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> needs an <kbd>Enter</kbd> before I get a fresh prompt line.

I can replicate the issue with a barebones Rails `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'sqlite3'
```

My shell is `zsh`, on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. `$JAVA_HOME` is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`, but it might have still been java-6 when I installed this interpreter, if that matters.

**Update: Some fixes**

The missing prompt character is apparently caused by the `IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE]` getting set to `:NULL` by the Rails console.  For regular `irb`, mine gets set to `:RVM` (apparently rvm does this in `~/.rvm/scripts/irb.rb`; I ruled out rvm causing this issue by commenting out the script).  Providing a `:PROMPT_MODE` value in `~/.irbrc` fixes this.  I thought maybe a similar issue was causing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> problems by changing `:IGNORE_SIGINT` and `:IGNORE_EOF`, but they are both set to their default values.

Tab completion and arrow keys get fixed by setting `:USE_READLINE` to true.

Here's my current `~/.irbrc` that seems to fix said issues:

```
require 'irb/completion'

IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE]  = :SIMPLE
IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = true
IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT]  = true
```

Answer (score 6):

Running the console with the following fixed these sorts of problems for me:

```
jruby -Xlaunch.inproc=true -S rails c
```

If you don't like running that command every time, you can set an environment variable:

```
set JRUBY_OPTS=-Xlaunch.inproc=true
```

or

```
export JRUBY_OPTS=-Xlaunch.inproc=true
```

then

```
rails c
```

Comment: Works like a charm. On Windows a simple set JRUBY_OPTS=-Xlaunch.inproc=true and rails c acts like it should.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with Windows and the fix was to increase the "Number of Buffers" in the Command prompt settings.
Command Prompt -> Properties -> Options -> Number of Buffers
Default is 4, I changed to 8 and all worked well (I think 5 would work though)

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your issue, however I'm on Linux so not sure if there is an analogous option