# irb history not working, among other issues (jruby / windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, console, jruby, irb

I just set up jruby on my windows box. Got some problems with both irb and rails console:

- irb - using arrow keys to access history outputs gibberish (for example hitting up-key one time outputs something like `OH`). Strangely rails console (`rails c`) does not suffer from such issue.
- rails console - it seems to echo every entered command.
- rails console - when entering non-ascii chars it crashes

`a = "āžš"
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: ""\x83"" from Windows-1257 to UTF-8`

- rails console - when printing utf-8 encoded string (`puts Article.first.name`), it cripples non ascii chars. Data is fine (checked via mysql desktop client and `render text: Article.first.name` in rails app)

Any ideas what am i doing wrong? My irbrc and java/jruby versions:

`require 'irb/completion'
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :SIMPLE`

- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
- jruby 1.7.11 (1.9.3p392) 2014-02-24 86339bb on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
  1.7.0_51-b13 [Windows 8-amd64]

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of known issues with jruby and windows around how consoles are working.

[Rails console issues using JRuby: no prompt character, no tab completion, broken arrow keys, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649437/rails-console-issues-using-jruby-no-prompt-character-no-tab-completion-broken)

[check this link](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1096)